# Divergence theorem equality problem in application

Tags: integration, divergence-theorem

I have this vector field :

$\overrightarrow{F}$ = $x$$\overrightarrow{i}$ + $y$$\overrightarrow{j}$ + $2(1-z)$$\overrightarrow{k}$

And I want to calculate the flux integral over the surface $S_1$ :

$z = 1 - x^2 - y^2$ for $z > 0$

However, I'm not certain of how to apply the divergence theorem here and I reach different results depending on the process. My reasoning is that since $z > 0$, then the theorem cannot be directly applied. Given this, I tried to make a new surface $S_2$:

$1 = x^2 + y^2$ such that $S_1$ $\cup$ $S_2$ is closed (a paraboloid).

Then, would this following application be correct?

$\iint\limits_{S_1}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}} + \iint\limits_{S_2}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}}= \iiint\limits_{E}{{{\mathop{\rm div}\nolimits} \vec F\,dV}}\\$

Since ${\rm div}\vec F = \vec \nabla \cdot \vec F$ = $1 + 1 -2 = 0$ then we have:

$\iint\limits_{S_1}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}} + \iint\limits_{S_2}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}}= 0$

$\iint\limits_{S_1}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}} = -\iint\limits_{S_2}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}}$

$S_2$ is the unitary circle at $z = 0$, so $S_2: x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Therefore,

$\iint\limits_{S_1}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}} = -\iint\limits_{S_2}{{<x,y,2(1-z)> \cdot <2x,2y,0> dA}}$

$=-\iint\limits_{S_2}{{<x,y,2> \cdot <2x,2y,0> dA}}$

$=-2\iint\limits_{S_2}{{x^2 + y^2 dA}}$

$=-2$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1{{r^3 drd\theta}}$

$=-1/2$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}1 = -\pi$

But when I try to directly integrate for $S_1$ I get this:

$\iint\limits_{S_1}{{\vec F\cdot d\vec S}} = \iint\limits_{S_1}{{<x,y,2(1-1+x^2 + y^2)> \cdot <2x,2y,1> dA}} $

$= 4\iint\limits_{S_2}{x^2 + y^2dA}$

$= 4$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1{{r^3 drd\theta}} = 2\pi \neq -\pi$

I'm not too sure where I went wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your "base" of the paraboloid is misidentified. You've written the equation of a cylinder. What you *need* (and surely are visualizing) is a *disk* filled in at $z=0$, namely $\{(x,y,0): x^2+y^2\le 1\}$. Now proceed, and think carefully about orientations.

Comment: Thanks. Should've seen that. My normal vector was wrong given this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether the question states $ \ z \gt 0$ or $z \geq 0, \ z = 1 - x^2 - y^2$ represents only the paraboloid surface and does not include disk at $z = 0$.

Paraboloid surface $S_1: z = 1- x^2 - y^2, 0 \lt z \lt 1$

To apply divergence theorem we close the paraboloid surface with a disk $ \ S2: x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ at $z=0$. We later on will have to subtract flux through the disk from the total flux to get flux through the paraboloid surface.

$\vec F = (x, y, 2-2z)$

So $\nabla \cdot \vec F = 1 + 1 -2 = 0$ and hence flux through the entire surface ($S_1 \cup S_2$) is zero.

Flux through surface $S_2$:

Outward Normal vector to the surface $S_2$ is $(0, 0, -1)$.

So flux through $S_2$ is given by,

$\displaystyle \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} (x, y, 2) \cdot (0, 0, -1) \ dx \ dy = - 2\pi$

So flux through $S_1$ is $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! Realized I got the normal wrong for the disc as I calculated it for a cylinder (wrong orientation too). Dumb mistake. Also said it wasn't direct cause the initial surface wasn't closed.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just wanted to call out that even if the limit said $z \geq 0$ instead of $z \gt 0$, $z = 1-x^2-y^2$ would still mean just the paraboloid surface. So your starting approach of closing the surface with the disk at $z=0$ and subtracting flux through it later is correct in either case unless question specifies otherwise about the surface.